# Wammu, Samsung J700 error GetNextMemory code: 56

Tags: usb, samsung

I have got a (old) Samsung J700i. When connecting with a USB cabel to Wammu first the access was denied. Now it is oké... 
However, when I try to get info out from the phone... I get error message:

```
Error whlie communicating with phone
Desciption: Internal phone error.
Function: GetNextMemory
Error code: 56
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04
   and
   Wammu 0.36
   Running on Python 2.7.3
   Using wxPython 2.8.12.1
   Using python-gammu 1.31.0 and Gammu 1.31.0

How may I access data on the phone?

Thanks,

Tamas

Comment: Wammu will allow you to gain access to the device in several ways and/or for different purposes. Which task is that you are trying to achieve? Are you sure you marked your phone in the proper mode? For dialing and sending/receiving sms your telephone must be in the "Communications" mode. Please provide this information and/or make sure your phone is in the proper mode. Remember that if your phone is being recognized as a SD, MicroSD reader or Data Connection you may receive an error in Wammu. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
What do you mean by "mode"? How do I change mode on my phone?
First of all I would like to read data from the phone to the Ubuntu, like the conatcs, calendar events, photos, videos. And, afterwards, I would like to load the same kind of data from the PC to the phone

Comment: By default the majority of the mobile devices are in "data connection mode" which means that: once connected, the device itself is recognized as a micro sd card reader device, thus allowing you to read/write photos, videos, music and so on. For the tasks related to read the contacts, calendar, events and other cellphone related stuff, you must dive in the configuration of your cellphone (usually under "connections") and change its mode to "Communications" or whatever your cellphone allows you to. Depending on the stuff in your cellphone's software is what you will be able to do in Wammu.

Comment: Hello Geppetvs ! 
Thanks... I found "PC connections" on my phone. It has 2 options: "Samsung PC Studio" and "Mass storage". It is by default in the first one. Here, at least the phone is recognised. When setting to Mass storage... it is not even seen, at all. 
However, no way to get any data out of the phone... at all. :(

Any further suggestion? 

Thanks for being with me! Greetings. T.

Comment: I added details and previous comments to my answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Wammu will allow you to gain access to the device in several ways and/or for different purposes. Which task is that you are trying to achieve? Are you sure you marked your phone in the proper mode? For dialing and sending/receiving sms your telephone must be in the "Communications" mode. Please provide this information and/or make sure your phone is in the proper mode. Remember that if your phone is being recognized as a SD, MicroSD reader or Data Connection you may receive an error in Wammu.

By default the majority of the mobile devices are in "data connection mode" which means that: once connected, the device itself is recognized as a micro sd card reader device, thus allowing you to read/write photos, videos, music and so on. For the tasks related to read the contacts, calendar, events and other cellphone related stuff, you must dive in the configuration of your cellphone (usually under "connections") and change its mode to "Communications" or whatever your cellphone allows you to. Depending on the stuff in your cellphone's software is what you will be able to do in Wammu.

*Your phone seems not to be fully supported, based on the [Wammu support page for Samsung SGH-J700](http://wammu.eu/phones/samsung/1987/), whose report dates from September 5, 2008. Tested with Gammu 1.15.0*

*It also seems that no new efforts have been made since that date, so you can only expect the results mentioned in the given site, as follows:*

> ## Reporter Note
>
> Seems to work reasonably well. Can actually read SIM contacts, no phone contacts as of yet though...

*Unfortunately I can't give further details on that phone. New mobile devices are having better support.*

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!
On the page you recommended it says:
Configuration

[gammu]
port = DEVICE NAME
connection = at
model = ALCATEL

HOW may I set these parameters? Where do I input them? 

(Is it really Alcatel???)

Greetings,

T.

Comment: Check this out: http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/config/ :)